# Page width overflows although no elements are outside its width

Tags: css

The page element as seen, ends exactly where the browser scroll-bar starts but a horizontal scroll bar is present.

Page with the problem: http://www.ivault.sg/shop/power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this in your css:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```